# Closing a session on a Perle IOLAN

Tags: terminal-server, serial

I am connecting to a serial port using a Perle IOLAN DS1.

I have noticed occasions when I have tried to log in and got an error message  “line not available - press any key” which we think is due to a previous session left “dangling”.

Is there a way of cleanly closing down my session to the host.

Answer (score 1):

You can telnet into the Iolan server and kill the port manually.

This is the process I remember from lots of old Iolan/Chase serial terminal servers, but it should be consistent for your unit.

telnet to the DS1 and run `su`

The default password is `iolan`

From there, you can show port status `sh po` or show usage `sh use`.

Since the DS1 is a single-port box, I guess you can probably kill the line or session:

`kill line` or on multi-port boxes `kill line PORTNUMBER`.

Try that for now...